# Euler Project 14 Longest Collatz Sequence

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, collatz-sequence

I have been working through the euler project and I have created the following code for [Problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14), which asks which starting number, under 1 million, produces the longest Collatz Sequence chain.

It takes a good minute to process.  Can I make it faster?

```
class Collatz:

    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 1

    def if_even(self, n):
        return int(n / 2)

    def if_odd(self, n):
        return int(n * 3 + 1)

    def decide(self, n):
        if (n & 1) == 0:
            return self.if_even(n)
        elif (n & 1) == 1:
            return self.if_odd(n)

    def iter_nums(self, n):
        if n == 1:
            return n
        self.c += 1
        n = self.decide(n)    
        self.iter_nums(n)

largest = 0

# col = Collatz()
# col.iter_nums(13)

# print(col.c)


for i in range(1000000, -1, -1):
    col = Collatz()
    col.iter_nums(i)
    if col.c > largest:
        largest = i

print(largest)
```

Comment: A few ideas: 1. don't create a new instance each time; 2. look into caching/memoization/dynamic programming; and 3. simplify the code to remove the redundant method calls, there's a lot of indirection that I don't think makes it easier to follow.

Comment: Did this code work for you ? First I had a RecursionError and then, after changing the recursion limit from 1000 to 100000, I had a segmentation fault :-(

Comment: Does the main loop even function properly?  It is comparing the length of the collatz sequence with `largest`, but storing the index, not the sequence length, in `largest`.  Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem really lends itself to [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). How many times to you really need to re-calculate the sequence starting at `10`, which never changes? Remember that value and reuse it.

I wrote this like:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def coll(num):
    if num == 1:
        return 1

    if num % 2:
        return 1 + coll(num * 3 + 1)

    return 1 + coll(num / 2)

longest = 0
for i in range(1, 1_000_001):
    this = coll(i)
    if this > longest:
        print(i, this)
        longest = this
```

Without taking any special steps to optimize this, just that memoization dropped the runtime to 2.8s on my laptop.

Answer (score 5):

**Useless calls to `int`**

When `n` is an integer:

- `n * 3 + 1` is an integer as well, you don't need to call `int`
- `int(n / 2)` can also be computed using the "floored quotient" with the `//` operator.

**You don't need a class**

I highly recommend watching [Jack Diederich's talk called "Stop Writing Classes"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). Classes are a great tool but they are not always needed, sometimes the problem can be solved with simple tools like functions.

In your case, the whole class can be restricted to a simple function, shorter, clearer, more efficient, easier to use.

```
def get_collatz_length(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return 1 + get_collatz_length((3 * n + 1) if (n & 1) else n // 2)
```

**You don't need recursion**

Once again, recursion can be a great way to write a concise solution for a given problem. However, in Python, it is **sometimes** best to avoid it: there is no [tail-recursion optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion) and the call stack has a [fairly limited size](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit).

You could write something like:

```
def get_collatz_length_loop(n):
    l = 1
    while n != 1:
        n = (3 * n + 1) if (n & 1) else n // 2
        l += 1
    return l
```

*To be continued: memoization*

*Is bitwise optimisation relevant?*

Comment: On my laptop, using `n % 2` is 4 seconds faster than using `n & 1`, over the 1 million collatz sequences.  YMMV.

Comment: Looking forward to the momoization option.....

Comment: @rolfl Sorry for the disappointment, I tend to give up the review when I realize the code never worked in the first place but I can see this got handled nonetheless in other answers :)

Answer (score 1):

A function which computes all the numbers in the Collatz sequence, and then returns just the length of the sequence, but not the actual numbers, seems like over optimization and/or specialization.  If one then wants the numbers in the Collatz sequence, you need to write effectively the same function again.

Instead, one can create a generator for Collatz sequences:

```
def collatz(n):
    yield n
    while n > 1:
        n =  n * 3 + 1  if  n % 2  else  n // 2
        yield n
```

Then, if you want a collatz sequence, you can easily get it:

```
>>> print(list(collatz(13)))
[13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

If you want the length of the sequence, you can quickly count the number of elements the generator emits without creating the actual list:

```
>>> sum(1 for _ in collatz(13))
10
```

Determining the length of the longest sequence for all starting numbers up to 1 million still takes under 30 seconds on my laptop, even with the overhead of the generator and `yield` statements.

```
>>> max(sum(1 for _ in collatz(i)) for i in range(1000001))
525
```

Determining the starting number for the sequence whose length is 525 is left as an exercise to the student.